# My site will not scroll at all

Tags: html, css

My website will not scroll vertically. This is stopping some of the content being displayed. I have tried to fix this but so far I have had no success using the the CSS overflow property. This is not scrolling in Google Chrome and is not bringing up any errors when I use the developer tools.

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Football Informer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/football/world-cup-goal-keeper-sport-website-header.jpg" class="header_img" alt="Error">
    <div class="text"> 
        <h1>The Football Informer</h1>
        <p class="strapline">The Home of Football</p>
    </div>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul> 

<div class="main_text">
    <p class="intro_home_page">Welcome to The Football Informer. This is the place to keep up to date with the footballing world.<br>
    Keep up to date with the big roomers about transfers and club takeovers. Or follow the Premier League fight in the leagues featured section. If you have any suggestions about the site please see the About page to see our contact information.</p>
    <div class="heading">
    <h1>Featured Articles</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="featured_articles_format">
        <div class="grey_background">
        <a href="http://thefootballfaithful.com/allardyce-reveals-cenk-tosun-struggles/" target="blank">
        <p class="article_title ">Allardyce reveals Cenk Tosun struggles.</p>
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/thefootballfaithful.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/img_7476.jpg?resize=660%2C330" class="interesting_article_img" alt="Error">
        </a>
        </div>
        <p class="article_strapline">Less than a month after joining Everton for £27m, Sam Allardyce has revealed that Cenk Tosun is struggling to adapt to life in the Premier League.</p>
        <p class="article_intro">The Turkish international sat out of the Toffees’ 5-1 humbling at the hands of Arsenal on Saturday evening, with the once outcasted Oumar Niasse selected to start the game.<br>
        Speaking after the defeat, Allardyce that the 26-year-old has struggled with the ‘pace and physicality of the game.’</p>
    </div>

    <div class="featured_articles_format">
        <div class="grey_background">
        <a href="http://www.skysports.com/football/news/11715/11237193/leeds-sack-head-coach-thomas-christiansen-after-cardiff-thrashing" target="blank">
        <p class="article_title ">Leeds sack head coach Thomas Christiansen after Cardiff thrashing</p>
        <img src="http://e0.365dm.com/17/09/16-9/20/skysports-thomas-christiansen-leeds_4110664.jpg?20170925180918" class="interesting_article_img" alt="Error">
        </a>
        </div>
        <p class="article_strapline">Leeds have sacked head coach Thomas Christiansen after a 4-1 thrashing at home to Cardiff on Saturday - their sixth Championship game without a win.</p>
        <p class="article_intro">Christiansen's side had been without a win since Boxing Day and a spate of ill-discipline had seen three different players sent-off in four games.<br>
        Leeds had been pushing for a place in the top six but slipped to 10th after the Cardiff defeat and the club announced his departure just over 24 hours later.<br>
        Statement "Leeds United can confirm that head coach Thomas Christiansen has left the club."
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="featured_articles_format">
        <div class="grey_background">
        <a href="http://www.skysports.com/football/news/11685/11240190/patrice-evra-completes-free-transfer-to-west-ham" target="blank">
        <p class="article_title ">Patrice Evra completes free transfer to West Ham</p>
        <img src="https://www.wessexfm.com/news/images/feed.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fe3.365dm.com%2F18%2F02%2F640x380%2Fskysports-patrice-evra-west-ham-united-premier-league-football-pose-posing_4225196.jpg%3F20180207173535" class="interesting_article_img" alt="Error">
        </a>
        </div>
        <p class="article_strapline">Patrice Evra has completed his free transfer to West Ham and signed a contract until the end of the season.</p>
        <p class="article_intro">Evra, 36, arrived at the club's Rush Green training complex on Wednesday morning before passing a medical and signing a short-term contract until the end of June 2018.<br>
        Sky Sports News understands Everton were also interested in the former Manchester United, Juventus and Monaco left-back but the player favoured a move to London.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="featured_articles_format">
        <div class="grey_background">
        <a href="http://www.skysports.com/football/news/11685/11240190/patrice-evra-completes-free-transfer-to-west-ham" target="blank">
        <p class="article_title ">Patrice Evra completes free transfer to West Ham</p>
        <img src="https://www.wessexfm.com/news/images/feed.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fe3.365dm.com%2F18%2F02%2F640x380%2Fskysports-patrice-evra-west-ham-united-premier-league-football-pose-posing_4225196.jpg%3F20180207173535" class="interesting_article_img" alt="Error">
        </a>
        </div>
        <p class="article_strapline">Patrice Evra has completed his free transfer to West Ham and signed a contract until the end of the season.</p>
        <p class="article_intro">Evra, 36, arrived at the club's Rush Green training complex on Wednesday morning before passing a medical and signing a short-term contract until the end of June 2018.<br>
        Sky Sports News understands Everton were also interested in the former Manchester United, Juventus and Monaco left-back but the player favoured a move to London.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height:150px;
}

.header_img {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    margin:0;
}

.text {
    font-size:26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:red;
}

.strapline {
    font-size:22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:red;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #666666;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

.main_text {
    margin-left:15%;
    width:85%;
    position: fixed;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.intro_home_page {
    font-size:20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.heading {
    background-color:red;
}

.article_title {
     color:white;
     font-size:24px;
}

.article_intro {
    font-size:18px;
}

.article_strapline {
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.grey_background {
    background-color:grey;
    height:30px;
}

.interesting_article_img {
    height:165px;
    width:330px;
    float: left;
}

img { 
    border: 0;  
}

p, h1 {
     margin: 0;
   }

.featured_articles_format{
    height:195px;
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and I hope that I have asked a precise enough question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `.main-text` style. The position fixed is preventing scrolling.

```
.main_text {
    margin-left:15%;
    width:85%;
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This will fix the scrolling problem, may have to refactor the markup to make it look proper. Maybe look into using a css library/framework. Save you a lot of time and effort.

http://jsbin.com/qabewarawi/1/edit?html,css,output